# How to active custom powerplan with powershell?

Tags: powershell

So there's one way to do this, with `powercfg /l`. Then copy the GUID and type `powercfg /s [GUID]`. But what I wanted is there any way to do this without copying the GUID. So when you run the script, you instantly active the custom power plan. What I mean by custom power plan is Ultimate Performance.

Comment: Yes; You have to have a license to Windows 10 Professional for Workstations since it’s a feature of that version; easier to just copy the power plan

Comment: **I suggest forgoing `powercfg` in favor of WMI:** https://superuser.com/a/1796437/320611

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the output of `powercfg /l` into PSObjects

```
$powerSchemes = powercfg /l | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '^Power Scheme GUID:\s*([-0-9a-f]+)\s*\(([^)]+)\)\s*(\*)?') {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            GUID       = $matches[1]
            SchemeName = $matches[2]
            Active     = $matches[3] -eq '*'
        }
    }
}

# if you want to view the schemes we've parsed into objects:
# $powerSchemes
```

Next, in code select the scheme from its custom name, for instance:

```
$customScheme = $powerSchemes | Where-Object { $_.SchemeName -eq 'MyCustomPowerScheme' }
```

and set the scheme active (if not active already) using

```
if (!$customScheme.Active) {
    powercfg /s $($customScheme.GUID)
}
```

Regex details:

```
^                       Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character)
Power\ Scheme\ GUID:    Match the characters “Power Scheme GUID:” literally
\s                      Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   *                    Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(                       Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   [-0-9a-f]            Match a single character present in the list below
                        The character “-”
                        A character in the range between “0” and “9”
                        A character in the range between “a” and “f”
      +                 Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)                      
\s                      Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   *                    Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\(                      Match the character “(” literally
(                       Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   [^)]                 Match any character that is NOT a “)”
      +                 Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)                      
\)                      Match the character “)” literally
\s                      Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   *                    Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(                       Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3
   \*                   Match the character “*” literally
)?                      Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

Comment: Wow thankyou, this is so helpful. UPVOTE

Answer (score 0):

In order to activate custom power plan with PowerShell you can write a PowerShell script. In the script you need to execute `powercfg /l`, parse the output for the GUID and then call `powercfg /s` with the GUID that you found earlier.

If you have any troubles writing the script, feel free to detail *concrete* programming problem on https://stackoverflow.com/ for help.

Comment: Is there no other way?? I mean without I need to copy the GUID

Comment: Yep, let the script do it for you behind the hood, so you do not have to.

Comment: Ooo so there is no way to bypass the GUID Copy Paste step

Comment: @BransRma - You could upgrade to Windows 10 Professional for Workstations and the Ultimate PowerPlan would already exist

Comment: If the Power Plan exists, you can just use PowerShell to query and activate it via WMI, as [explained](https://superuser.com/a/1796437/320611). Why are everyone suggesting the `powercfg.exe` Utility. Also, sorry for reviving three years later.

Answer (score 0):

**❖** You can also to active your Plan/Scheme:

```
$(powercfg.exe /L) -match 'Ultimate'|% {powercfg.exe /S $_.split(" ")[3]}
```

```
$(powercfg.exe /L) -match ':'|% {$_}
```

❖  Results:

```
Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced)
Power Scheme GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c  (High performance)
Power Scheme GUID: a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a  (Power saver) *
Power Scheme GUID: e9a42b02-d5df-448d-aa00-03f14749eb61  (Ultimate Performance)
```

You can get it by simply filtering the output strings by space, your strings are in the 3rd occurrence of the lines that contain `"You Plan/Scheme Name"`

```
$(powercfg.exe /L) -match 'Ultimate'|% {$_.split(" ")[3]}
```

❖  Results:

```
e9a42b02-d5df-448d-aa00-03f14749eb61
```

Answer (score 0):

No one wants to mention **WMI**?

##### To query the power plans, including the active one:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PowerPlan -NS root\cimv2\power -Filter "isActive='true'"
```

You can remove the `-Filter` argument to list all other power plans.

##### To make one active:

```
$plan = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PowerPlan -Namespace root\cimv2\power -Filter "ElementName='Ultimate Performance'"
Invoke-WmiMethod -InputObject $plan -Name Activate
```

---

When dealing with internal Windows affairs with PowerShell, I don't understand the mentality where the first instinct is to call an executable like **`PowerCfg`** and parse its output, especially when you can use objects like WMI.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Get-PowerScheme {
    param (
        [string]$SchemeName,
        [string]$SchemeGuid,
        [string]$SchemesDetails     # optional
    )

    if (($SchemeName) -and ($SchemeGuid)) {
        Write-Host "`n Error: only one criteria is permitted for searching a power scheme" -ForegroundColor "Red"
        Write-Host " '-SchemeName `"$SchemeName`"' and '-SchemeGuid `"$SchemeGuid`"' arguments can't be input together ...`n" -ForegroundColor "Red"
        return $Null
    }

    $PowerSchemeObjectArray = @()

    $SearchByName = $False
    if (([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($SchemeGuid)) -and ($SchemeName)) { $SearchByName = $True }

    $SearchForAll = $False
    if (([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($SchemeName)) -and ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($SchemeGuid))) { $SearchForAll = $True }

    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($SchemesDetails)) { $SchemesDetails = powercfg.exe -LIST | Out-String }
    $PowerSchemes = $SchemesDetails -split [Environment]::NewLine

    foreach ($PowerScheme in $PowerSchemes) {

        if ($PowerScheme -match "GUID") {

            # Extract the scheme power name between "(" and ")"
            $PowerSchemeName = $PowerScheme -match '\((.*?)\)'
            $PowerSchemeName = $matches[1]
            # Extract the scheme GUID between ":" and "(", then remove spaces
            $PowerSchemeGuid = $PowerScheme -match ':\s*(.*?)\('
            $PowerSchemeGuid = $matches[1].Trim()
            # Check if current power scheme is active
            $IsActive = $False
            if ($PowerScheme[-1] -eq "*") {$IsActive = $True}

            $PowerSchemeObject = [PSCustomObject]@{Name = $PowerSchemeName; GUID = $PowerSchemeGuid; IsActive = $IsActive}
            $AddPowerSchemeObject = $False

            if ($SearchForAll) {
                $AddPowerSchemeObject = $True
            } else {
                if ($SearchByName) {
                    if ($PowerSchemeName -match "$SchemeName") {
                        $AddPowerSchemeObject = $True
                    }
                } else {
                    if ($PowerSchemeGuid -match "$SchemeGuid") {
                        $AddPowerSchemeObject = $True
                    }
                }
            }
            if ($AddPowerSchemeObject) { $PowerSchemeObjectArray += $PowerSchemeObject }
        }
    }
    return $PowerSchemeObjectArray
}

$MyCustomPowerScheme = Get-PowerScheme -SchemeName "The Name of My Custom Power Plan"
$Result = powercfg.exe /SETACTIVE $MyCustomPowerScheme.GUID
```

Comment: Code without any explanation is useless. 
Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Answer (score 0):

Managing power scheme is very particular in Windows. Activate method is no longer implemented ... This command doesn't work anymore : Invoke-WmiMethod -InputObject $plan -Name Activate

So that you have to use the command : powercfg.exe /SETACTIVE PowerSchemeGUID

Most of the time, you have to use 'powercfg.exe' and analyse the output to manage power scheme.