# Need to create a batch or PS file help fix powercfg issues

Tags: powershell, batch, powercfg

I have the beginings of a script that will do the following:

```
powercfg /L >> c:\folder\powercfglst.txt
```

Which gives me a file with the following in it.

```
*Existing Power Schemes (* Active)
-----------------------------------
Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260aaaa  (Power Management Plan)
Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced)
Power Scheme GUID: 49ef8fc0-bb7f-488e-b6a0-f1fc77ec649b  (Dell)
Power Scheme GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c  (High performance)
Power Scheme GUID: 9f232b21-3864-4cf2-be7e-9a7ec8c2db7d  (AEM) *
Power Scheme GUID: a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a  (Power saver)*
```

I need a script that will parse the GUID# out and put it in another file
or to make the original file only list the guid#.

From there then I plan to do a delete of all powercfg's and import a custom one and make it active

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to active custom powerplan with powershell](https://superuser.com/questions/1603593/how-to-active-custom-powerplan-with-powershell)

Comment: If someone is using PS, then using the native WMI object is a better way than to parse the output of `powercfg.exe`. Explained [here](https://superuser.com/a/1796437/320611).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to extract/parse the GUID, you can try the following:

```
$regex = '[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}'
(powercfg /l) -split " " -match $regex > myGUID.txt
```

**Contents of myGUID.txt** (for my PC)

```
381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e
49ef8fc0-bb7f-488e-b6a0-f1fc77ec649b
```

Answer (score 0):

```ps1
$(powercfg /L)-match ':'|%{$_.split(" ")[3]}
```

You can get it by simply filtering the output strings by space, your strings are in the 3rd occurrence of the lines that contain `":"`

```ps1
$(powercfg.exe /L) -match ':' | % {
    $_.split(" ")[3] } >>C:\folder\powercfglst.txt
```

- Contents of C:\folder\powercfglst.txt...

```ps1
381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e
8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c
a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a
e9a42b02-d5df-448d-aa00-03f14749eb61
```